# Entity Framework ensure objects get inserted in order

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a table Rules on my database. I insert rules like:

```
Rule[] rulesToInsert = // some array of rules to insert

using(var db = new MyEntities())
{
     foreach(var rule in rulesToInsert)
         db.Rules.Add(rule);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**When I retrieve later the rules that I have just added I notice they are in a different order.** What is the best way to retrieve them in the order I added them? Should I call `db.SaveChanges()` every time I add a new rule? Or should I add a new column called SortOrder? **Why are the items not being added in the order I added them?**

### Edit

The id is a guid (string) because one rule can have other rules. In other words I am creating a tree structure. (The rules table has a foreign key to itself). It was crashing when I used the primary key as an integer and it autoincremented so I just used a guid instead. I guess I will add a separate column called sort order.

Comment: How are you ordering them when you retrieve them, what are you ordering on? id?

Comment: Nope id is a guid. I have no column to sort by. I guess I have to add it.

Comment: When you retrieve rows from a SQL-based database, if you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause, the database engine / optimizer is free to pick any ordering that makes sense depending on the indexes and whatnot it uses to retrieve the rows through. So the solution here is to specify an `ORDER BY` clause, and it follows from that that you need something stable to order on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your items to be inserted in the order you add them in the foreach statement, you have to make a **big** compromise, to call the `db.SaveChanges` in each iteration.

```
foreach(var rule in rulesToInsert)
{
    db.Rules.Add(rule);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I say that's a **big** compromise, because *for each rule you have to insert you have to make a round-trip to the database*, instead of doing only one round-trip as in your original code.

One possible workaround, it would be to add an extra column in the corresponding table in your database, that would hold the information of order. If you do so, you could add one more property in the rule object and refactor a bit your code. Then you will have the expected result.

Comment: Inserting them in one order has no effect on how they are retrieved if used without `order by`

Comment: I agree with Magnus. Insert order doesn't dictate natural order. The db server will decide where to inject that row in the table based on a number of factors.  Usually it's at the end, but it's not guaranteed. If you want it reliable, your best bet is to add a column to sort by.

Comment: @Donwvoter, could you please explain me what's wrong in order to correct or delete my answer? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Tables have **no** sort order (new rows are not guaranteed to be added to the end or any other place). The only safe way to retrieve rows in any particular order is to have a query with `Order by`.
So yes you will need to add a `SortOrder` column.

Comment: OH MY GOD THIS KIND OF ANSWER ONCE AGAIN! This is not about order of rows in table in the database. This is about order which is fed to INSERT statement, the order in which identity is assigned! See the answer below! There is no gurantee that entities are inserted in order in which are added to the change tracker and thus sooner entity is not guaranteed to recieve lower identity.

Comment: Interesting, did not know ef did not keep the added order. I suppose you would skip identity in that case and just set the order column values yourself.